# My code execution breaks when it try to invoke a service after 8 times concurrently call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My web application is running on spring 4.x and Hibernate.

Code snippet For Database configuration :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pearson.esp.dao")
public class DbConfiguration {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_RELEASE_MODE = "hibernate.connection.release_mode";
    //private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

       @Resource
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {

                 BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
                dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
                dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
                dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
                dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

                return dataSource;
        }


        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.pearson.esp" });
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            HibernateTransactionManager tm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            tm.setDefaultTimeout(30);
            tm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
            return tm;
        }



        private Properties hibProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
            //properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, "true");
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_RELEASE_MODE, "after_transaction");

            return properties;       
    }


}
```

This code execution breaks when it try to invoke a service after 8 times concurrently call. Exception is :

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [esp-webservice] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1104)
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
 org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:514)
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.authenticateUser(Unknown Source)
 com.pearson.controller.impl.LoginControllerImpl.login(LoginControllerImpl.java:101)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can any one help me to resolve it out!
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when a connection is being fetched from the connection pool. Seems like connections are not returned to the pool in time, which might have several reasons.

- The transaction is not finished before making the next request (connection release mode `after_transaction` is being used)
- The connection pool is not large enough
- Any existing manual connection handling doesn't close connections

Solving the problem depends on the implementation which is not completely shown here.